# Hiding UIButton(which added programatically) once view is hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Goal:
Hide a UIButton(w/ image) once a view is hidden.

I have a layout whereby the map view can be hidden when user taps(`UITapGestureRecognizer`) on the screen. When this happen, I would like to hide the "follow user button" triangle. Currently I am not able to do it.

[image]

What I've tried: (from multiple google/SO posts)

1)

```
followUserButton.removeFromSuperview()
```

2. 

```
followUserButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
followUserButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
```

3. 

```
followUserButton.setImage(image:nil for: .normal)
```

4. 

the last one I tried is basically just making the image black in color (to blend into the background). This does look like a success, but (see gif image), for some reason, the first click, will still show the button (very light black/grey - in the bottom middle of image). Click again, the map view comes on, then click again and it finally disappears

```
followUserButton.tintColor = .black
```

5. followUserButton.isHidden = true

this is how I'm adding my button programatically

```
  var followUserImage: UIImage!
  var followUserButton: UIButton!

  override func viewDidLoad() {    
    setupFollowUserButton()
  }

  func setupFollowUserButton() {
          addFollowUserButton()
          self.view.addSubview(followUserButton)
          constraintFollowUserButton()
      }      

  func hideFollowUserButton() {
    if vcTrainMapView.isHidden {
      if followUserButton != nil {
        //  followUserButton.removeFromSuperview()
        //  followUserButton.tintColor = .black
        followUserButton.isHidden = true
      }
    } else if followUserButton != nil {
      followUserButton.tintColor = .lightGray
    }
  }

    func addFollowUserButton() {
        followUserButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
        followUserImage = UIImage(named: "follow_user_high")
        followUserButton.setImage(followUserImage, for:.selected)
        followUserImage = (UIImage(named: "follow_user"))
        followUserButton.setImage(followUserImage, for: .normal)
        followUserButton.tintColor = .lightGray
        followUserButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
      }
    
      @objc private func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.followUserStatus = !self.followUserStatus
        sender.isSelected.toggle()
      }
      
      func constraintFollowUserButton() {
        followUserButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        followUserButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vcTrainMapView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        followUserButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vcTrainMapView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        followUserButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        followUserButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
      }
```

this is what I've achieved w/ #3 above. (the button is very light in the gif)
[image]

Comment: Could you share how you store the followUserButton property ?

Comment: Have you tried just setting the button to hidden? 
followUserButton.isHidden = true
Something like that?

Comment: @James yes.. that was what I also tried. (added in Original Post).

Comment: @πter I added how the property is instantiated.

Comment: I don't see why isHidden should not work, are you sure it gets called? Consider uploading the code where you hide it

Comment: @LucaSfragara added. The ```hideFollowUserButton``` is where I basically tried to put the codes.

Comment: a small point, but you could name your functions more clearly.  `addFollowUserButton` doesn't add the button, it creates it, and `setupFollowUserButton` is the one which adds it.  Perhaps these should be renamed `createFollowUserButton` and `addFollowUserButton` ?

Comment: have you tried adding the button to `vcTrainMapView` instead of the main view?  then it should be hidden automatically when the map view is hidden

Comment: @Russell fair point. Needs cleanup for sure. Right now it's "don't refactor it when still meddling around" stage.

Comment: @Russell thanks for that nugget. Just tried it ```self.vcTrainMapView.addSubview(followUserButton)``` and it does look like it doing the hiding w/o needing to call ```hideFollowUserButton``` at all. I'll need more testing on a few other scenarios and what not. If you could post your comment as an answer, I'll upvote it and once I try out more and it works, I'll accept it.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be hiding and showing a button at the same time as a detail view (your map view), and you're displaying the button so that it looks like it's on that view, you could just add the button directly to that view rather than the view controller main view.

You can, of course, still control the action of the button from the view controller, but if it's added to the map view then the button will be hidden when the map view is hidden.